# Explaining a bad exam result at my annual review

Tags: phd, negative-results

As I posted yesterday, I've just taken an exam and failed (quite badly might I add). The course was externally hosted as part of my PhD training in my first year so it won't look very good on my record which has me very worried. I turned the exam in yesterday but I know I've failed, I left half unanswered. I just don't know what's happened to me.

I don't have an excuse for why I've performed so terribly other than the questions were harder (to me) than previous years And I'm burnt out.

How do I explain this failure to the panel?

Comment: What country are you in? What is this "record"? Degree transcript or something else?

Comment: @astronat the record of results they keep on my PhD

Comment: Will that affect your ability to graduate? Who will look at this record in the future? I come from a system where there are no grades or exams during the PhD, so I'm trying to understand how possibly failing an external course will affect the outcome of your PhD.

Comment: @astronat that's why I'm concerned ,they haven't clarified the results of failing it but I'll still have to answer why I didn't pass it

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities. One is that the exam was just more difficult than it was intended to be and that others are in the same situation and so it won't really affect you much. Sometimes questions on exams are misstated and lead students astray, for example.

My advice it that sort of situation, in general but too late to implement now, is to say *something* sensible for every question if possible, rather than just leaving things blank. That might be helpful in future.

The other possibility is that you were expected to know/do things that you weren't prepared for. In that situation, there isn't really much to say other than that you weren't prepared and intend to do better it future.

But in this situation, you can also ask for advice from faculty about what sort of actions you might have taken to avoid the problem. They might have some actual advice and know both you and the topic.

And a single failure on a single exam (other than a qualifying exam) isn't disqualifying for most. It happens. You may just have to move on.

Comment: I attempted every question but I couldn't fully answer some of them :(